# $\sigma$-algebra of the past intersection/minimum property

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ over a set $\Omega$ with $A,B,C\subseteq \Omega$ and $B,C\in\mathcal{F}$ and $A\cap B\cap C\in \mathcal{F}$. Can I show that $A\in\mathcal{F}$ or $A\cap B\in\mathcal{F}$ and $A\cap C\in\mathcal{F}$?

All set theoretic operations I tried failed. I'm actually solving this for another related question but if I did not miss anything it should come down to this calculation without any more extra conditions.

**Edit:**
The problem I'm trying to solve has to do with filtered probability spaces, more specific:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_{\cdot}=(\mathcal{F}_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N_0}},\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space and $\sigma,\tau:\Omega\to\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ two $\mathcal{F}_{\cdot}$-stopping times. Show that $\mathcal{F}_{\tau\wedge\sigma}=\mathcal{F}_{\tau}\cap\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$, where $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}=\{E\in\mathcal{F}_{\cdot}|E\cap\{\tau\le k\}\in\mathcal{F}_k\,\,\forall k\in\mathbb{N_0} \}$ (the $\sigma$-algebra of the $\tau$-past).

I can prove the inclusion "$\supseteq$". But for the other one I have $E\in\mathcal{F}_{\tau\wedge\sigma}=\mathcal{F}_{\min(\tau,\sigma)}$ so $E\cap\{\tau\wedge\sigma\le k\}\in\mathcal{F}_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$, so $E\cap\{\tau\le k\}\cap\{\sigma\le k\}\in\mathcal{F}_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$ and I have to show that $E\cap\{\tau\le k\},E\cap\{\sigma\le k\}\in\mathcal{F}_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$. I already know that $\{\tau\le k\},\{\sigma\le k\}\in\mathcal{F}_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N_0}$ since $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are $\mathcal{F}_{\cdot}$-stopping times. Hence I tried to show the statement with the calculation I proposed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty false, and looks like you need much stronger hypotheses: just pick a set not in the $\sigma$-algebra which is disjoint from atleast one of $B$ or $C$.

More explicitly, let $\Omega = \Bbb{R}$ for example, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the smallest $\sigma$ algebra containing $\{1\}$. Then, $\mathcal{F} = \left\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1\}^c, \Bbb{R}\right\}$. Take $B = \{1\}$, and (any) $C \in \mathcal{F}$, and take $A = \{2\}$ for instance. Then, $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$, but $A \notin \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: An even more intuitive counterexample is, in the standard Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R$, $B = C = [0,1]$, and $A$ such that $A \cap B = [0,1]$, while $A \setminus B$ is some non-measurable set.

Comment: @giobrach thanks for the comment, but I only just started measure theory and haven't seen the proof for existence of non-Borel measurable sets (and wanted to avoid any potential objections against invoking axiom of choice), so I wanted to discuss something which I was pretty certain of.

Comment: I understand, I was just trying to appeal to your sense of (visual? physical?) intuition

Comment: I see. I noticed that for my needs it would be enough to show that $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ are in $\mathcal{F}$. Do you think, this is true?

Comment: @mathemagician99 No. Take $B = C = \{1\}$ and $A$ as in my above example. The intersections are empty, but $A$ doesn't belong to the $\sigma$-algebra. If you add the condition that $B \cup C = \Omega$, then it is true. On a similar note, here is another possible sufficient condition: suppose we have many countably many measurable sets $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{F}$ such that $\bigcup_{n}B_n = \Omega$, and such that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $A \cap B_n \in \mathcal{F}$. Then, $A = \bigcup_n (A \cap B_n)$ being the countable union of measurable sets is measurable.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay. I edited my post and explained the problem, I want to solve. I would appreciate if you take a look at it if you know filtered probability spaces.

Comment: @mathemagician99 haha I'm afraid that's something I'm not familiar with (as I said, I only have a very basic understanding of measure theory). Hopefully someone else can help you out. (Also, consider making the title more descriptive to attract more attention)